# AWS: Call jupyter notebook from step function or lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, jupyter-notebook, aws-step-functions

I created a python notebook called 'test.ipynb' in SageMaker to retrieve a csv file from my S3 bucket, manipulate the data, calculate values, create a new csv file and save it back into the S3 bucket.  This part works.

I want to test triggering it from a step function or from a lambda function.  For step functions, I added a SageMaker event / item / step called StartNotebookInstance that successfully starts the notebook instance but the next step is to start the notebook 'test.ipynb' but I do not see anything in that step that allows me to specify the notebook name.  I also do not see the equivalent to 'RunNotebook'.  Did anyone successfully call a notebook from a step function?  If so, how did you do it?

If it is not possible, perhaps I can create a lambda function to call 'test.ipynb'.  Is anyone familiar with the code to do so or can someone point me in the right direction?  I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSdVAa7b5Oc) but it uses api gateway which I am unsure I need.  I also checked the [aws lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) and [step](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/how-step-functions-works.html) documents but did not find any solution to this behavior.  I also tried to use aws data pipeline but that api is blocked due to security reasons.

I am also wondering if there is a more practical / efficient way to call a python notebook because I did not find any solutions and maybe it is because it is not a recommended way.

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Comment: I looked into this question further (I spent at least one week on it) and discovered it is discouraged to call a jupyter notebook from a step function or from lambda and that maybe explains why is is difficult to do so.  The notebook must constantly be running and this is not efficient / high overhead.   The best thing is to create a system from start to finish in jupyter notebook or a well designed data pipeline.

Comment: I will try a different method but in case anyone else has the same question, I hope this helps.  I found this advice in a few sites (I forgot to write the web sources).  It is not about writing code here and there and invoking it, it is about efficiency because the costs add up quickily with AWS.